# How do I fix 'Type Error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a Pokemon Battle Simulator (like pokemon showdown in a way) and, during the creation of the battle step (where damage is calculated), an error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` occurs.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def fight():
    moveused1 = moveset1.get()
    moveused2 = moveset2.get()
    if moveused1 == "Tackle":
        movetype1 = "Normal"
        moverange1 = "Physical"
        power1 = "40"
    if moveused2 == "Tackle":
        movetype2 = "Normal"
        moverange2 = "Physical"
        power2 = "40"
    if moverange1 == "Physical":
       Pokemon1Damage = ((2 * 100 / 5 + 2) * power1 * Attack1 / Defence1 / 50 + 2)
    if moverange1 == "Special":
       Pokemon1Damage = ((2 * 100 / 5 + 2) * power2 * SpAttack2 / SpDefence2 / 50 + 2)

def start():
    global moveset1
    global moveset2
    global HP1
    global Attack1
    global SpAttack1
    global Defence1
    global SpDefence1
    global HP2
    global Attack2
    global SpAttack2 
    global Defence2
    global SpDefence2
    setup.withdraw()
    battle = Tk()
    battle.title(pokemon1 + " VS " + pokemon2)
    battle.geometry("600x400")
    battle.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
    if pokemon1 == "Bulbasaur":
       HP1 = "231"
       Attack1 = "134"
       SpAttack1 = "166"
       Defence1 = "134"
       SpDefence1 = "166"
    if pokemon2 == "Bulbasaur":
       HP2 = "231"
       Attack2 = "134"
       SpAttack2 = "166"
       Defence2 = "134"
       SpDefence2 = "166"
    move1 = move1select.get()
    move2 = move2select.get()
    move3 = move3select.get()
    move4 = move4select.get()
    Label(battle, text="Battle").pack()
    Label(battle, text="").pack()
    Label(battle, text=pokemon1 + "'s Move").pack()
    moveset1 = ttk.Combobox(battle, state="readonly", values=(move1, move2, move3, move4))
    moveset1.current(0)
    moveset1.pack()
    move5 = move5select.get()
    move6 = move6select.get()
    move7 = move7select.get()
    move8 = move8select.get()
    Label(battle, text="").pack()
    Label(battle, text=pokemon2 + "'s Move").pack()
    moveset2 = ttk.Combobox(battle, state="readonly", values=(move5, move6, move7, move8))
    moveset2.current(0)
    moveset2.pack()
    Button(battle, text="Fight", command=fight).pack()
```

Edit: Here is the full error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\colli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\colli\Desktop\Pokemon Battle Buddy\Pokemon Battle Buddy.py", line 19, in fight
    Pokemon1Damage = ((2 * 100 / 5 + 2) * power1 * Attack1 / Defence1 / 50 + 2)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mre].

Comment: Add the full traceback. It is more useful than you think at the moment.

Comment: Why are you setting variables to the string representation of numbers and then trying to use them in an expression?

Comment: I got different errors when I run your code

Comment: @BálintCséfalvay This isn't my full code, just what I think I need to show, that might be why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are multiplying strings and float.
Here:

```
if moverange1 == "Physical":
   Pokemon1Damage = ((2 * 100 / 5 + 2) * power1 * Attack1 / Defence1 / 50 + 2)
if moverange1 == "Special":
   Pokemon1Damage = ((2 * 100 / 5 + 2) * power2 * SpAttack2 / SpDefence2 / 50 + 2)
```

`power1`, `power2`, `Attack1`, `Defence1`, `SpAttack2`, `SpDefence2` are all strings.
You should replace them with integers where you define them in your code.

Comment: How do I that? I didn't know they were strings and I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Here is how you declare a string: `power1 = "40"`, and here is how you declare an integer: `power1 = 40`. So just remove the quotes around the number. Have a look at [Python's types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: I've done that, but I still get the same error. Sorry if I'm just stupid, I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Of course you don't have to do that only for `power1`, but for all the variables involved in the multiplication. Did you change them all?

Comment: Whoops, no. I changed all of them but 2. They were in a different part of the script. It works now, thanks for the help!